# How to handle exception when doing List.Sort

Tags: c#, sorting

I'm doing a sort on a List which is causing an exception (FormatException). I think the issue is that one of the users has a space character or something in the field value versus an actual value. How do I ignore this exception and allow the other values to sort, or at least not break the application?

```
users.Sort((x, y) => DateTime.Parse(y.createdDate).CompareTo(DateTime.Parse(x.createdDate)));
```

> **Error:** An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 5):

You have to try to parse, if it fails, default the sort order. You need a little more code though to do this:

```
users.Sort((x, y) =>
    {
        DateTime xcd, ycd;
        bool y_ok = DateTime.TryParse(y.createdDate, out ycd);
        bool x_ok = DateTime.TryParse(x.createdDate, out xcd);

        if (!x_ok && !y_ok)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        if (!x_ok)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        if (!y_ok)
        {
            return -1;
        }

        return ycd.CompareTo(xcd);
    }
```